# Combine 2 scripts into 1 file

Tags: javascript

I have two scripts that load in my head area which are:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var myDate = new Date();
       var myStamp = ""+myDate.getDate()+myDate.getMonth()+myDate.getFullYear()+myDate.getHours()+myDate.getMinutes();
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://scriptlocation.com/js/script.js?' + myStamp + '"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src=""https://scriptlocation.com/js/script2.js?'+SVNInfo.revision+'"><\/script>');
    </script>
```

My ideal scenario would be to merge these two into 1 javascript file, so I've tried to create a new file which contains the following:

```
       var myDate = new Date();
       var myStamp = ""+myDate.getDate()+myDate.getMonth()+myDate.getFullYear()+myDate.getHours()+myDate.getMinutes();
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://scriptlocation.com/js/script.js?' + myStamp + '"><\/script>');
       document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src=""https://scriptlocation.com/js/script2.js?'+SVNInfo.revision+'"><\/script>');
```

however that does not seem to work as the script is not being loaded properly. Do I need to rewrite / change something to have this working correctly?

Some advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from where SVNInfo.revision is coming?

Comment: Probably don't work because `document.write` is **evil**.

Comment: You need to merge the scripts blocks or the "script.js" and "script2.js"?

Comment: @GabrielSantos: The scripts are required to load a certain booking engine - this specific code is outlined on the original documentation which is here: http://www.cartrawler.com/Cartrawler_AJAX_Booking_Engine.pdf (Page 4 - Required Javascript files)

Comment: @AlvinWong: Is there any other way / method to have these scripts loaded / imported without using document.write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myStamp = (new Date()).getTime(), //easier way to get a relatively unique timestamp
        script1 = document.createElement('script'),
        script2 = document.createElement('script'),
        body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    script1.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script1.setAttribute('src', 'https://scriptlocation.com/js/script.js?' + myStamp);
    script2.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script2.setAttribute('src', 'https://scriptlocation.com/js/script2.js?' + SVNInfo.revision); //is SVNInfo.revision defined?
    body.appendChild(script1);
    body.appendChild(script2);
</script>
```

For the record, `document.write` is an extremely primitive (and not a friendly way) of adding scripts to the page. Just create them as elements and then add them to the DOM.

Comment: I thought using `script1.type="text/javascript"` and `script1.src="blah.js"` is enough?

Comment: You are correct. `script.type = 'text/javascript'` is probably enough. I was demonstrating DOM manipulation methods.

Comment: Thank you very much @pete - I will have a look into your solution!

Answer (score 2):

`SVNInfo` is defined by the first script. So you can't include the second script (whose source path includes the value of `SVNInfo`) until you've executed the first.

When you `document.write` content from a `<script>` block, it's adding new content for the HTML parser at the point just after the `</script>` end-tag of the current block. If that content itself includes a `<script>` element, then the script inside it cannot start to execute until the current script has finished. So the `</script><script>` tags break up the current script execution allowing the script inserted by `document.write` to run. You won't be able to put both writes into the same script without breaking this.

You may be able to do it the way pete suggests with inserting script elements directly into the DOM, avoiding the parser completely. Because no parser is involved, the inserted script can execute straight away, without waiting for the current script block to complete.

However, you will need to ensure that the first script element is added to the document and run before you attempt to set the `src` of the second script element, because you need `SVNInfo` to be ready. Also, you should append the scripts to the `<head>` element and not `<body>` because writing to an element that hasn't been completely parsed yet is likely to cause the page load to abort in IE.

It is also possible that this might still not work, if there's something in the second script that expects to be running from a `document.write`-invoked script. Can't really see from here as the script is unreadable compressed.

Given that the integration doc tells you what it wants you to do, I'd stick with that; even if you have a better way, they might change the script at some point in the future in a way that relies on the two `document.write` scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough details @bobince - very much appreciated.